# Pool of async tasks

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have a pool of tasks in a queue and would like to get done tasks from pull output result and put the new tasks. Is this correct way to do this? I periodically check if any task is completed. Creating task like this `task = asyncio.create_task(...)` is asynchronous? (Could it block the loop if we create big number of more complex tasks)?

```
import asyncio
from collections import deque
from random import randint


async def show_result(q):
    while True:
        done_task = await q.get()
        result = done_task.result()
        print(result)
        q.task_done()



async def some_work(n, delay):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    return f'task {n} with delay: {delay} completed'


async def tasks_worker(q, pool_size):
    """
    extract done tasks and put new
    """

    delay = get_task_param()
    tasks = deque([])

    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        # append new tasks
        tasks_to_add = pool_size - len(tasks)
        print(f"tasks_to_add: {tasks_to_add}")
        if tasks_to_add > 0:
            # append new tasks
            for _ in range(tasks_to_add):
                n, d = await delay.__anext__()
                print(f"add task: {n} with delay: {d}")
                task = asyncio.create_task(some_work(n, d))
                tasks.append(task)

        for _ in range(len(tasks)):
            task = tasks.popleft()
            if task.done():
                await q.put(task)
            else:
                tasks.append(task)


async def get_task_param():
    task_n = 0
    while True:
        task_n += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        yield task_n, randint(5, 10)


async def run(pool_size):
    q = asyncio.Queue()

    task_1 = asyncio.create_task(show_result(q))
    task_2 = asyncio.create_task(tasks_worker(q, pool_size))

    done, pending = await asyncio.wait({task_1, task_2}, return_when=asyncio.ALL_COMPLETED)
    print(done)
    print(pending)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    POOL_SIZE = 50

    try:
        asyncio.run(run(POOL_SIZE))
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

Comment: Your code is not idiomatic. You're supposed to use a queue to transfer work items from the producer to the consumer. You shouldn't need an additional `deque` because the queue already contains a deque. Could you explain what you need done, maybe there's a better/simpler way of achieving the same?

Comment: I need to send post requests periodically to 1000 servers but some of them sometimes doesn't respond quickly (time_out=~10s). I'd like to get responses which have already done and add the new requests tasks. I use Queue because I am going to run several different task_workers and collect done work in show_result(...)

Comment: Hi! Sorry for delayed answer. I've tried to implement the new version the same as your solution but have lots of timeouts. Is it possible to show you somehow two versions of my solutions? Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I need to send post requests periodically to 1000 servers but some of them sometimes doesn't respond quickly (time_out=~10s). I'd like to get responses which have already done and add the new requests tasks.

You should probably use one queue for assigning work and another for emitting results. You don't need to add the workers dynamically, you can add the tasks dynamically and have a fixed-size pool of workers process them in parallel as they come. For example:

```
import asyncio
from random import randint

async def some_work(n, delay):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    return f'task {n} with delay: {delay} completed'

async def worker(tasks, results):
    # individual worker task (sometimes called consumer)
    # - sequentially process tasks as they come into the queue
    # and emit the results
    while True:
        n, d = await tasks.get()
        result = await some_work(n, d)
        await results.put(result)

async def assigner(tasks):
    # come up with tasks dynamically and enqueue them for processing
    task_n = 0
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        task_n += 1
        await tasks.put((task_n, randint(5, 10)))

async def displayer(q):
    # show results of the tasks as they arrive
    while True:
        result = await q.get()
        print(result)

async def main(pool_size):
    tasks = asyncio.Queue(100)
    results = asyncio.Queue(100)
    workers = [asyncio.create_task(worker(tasks, results))
               for _ in range(pool_size)]
    await asyncio.gather(assigner(tasks), displayer(results), *workers)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    POOL_SIZE = 50
    asyncio.run(main(POOL_SIZE))
```

Queue bounds, arbitrarily chosen at 100 items, limit the maximum queue size and provide backpressure in case the assigner is consistently faster than the workers, or in case the workers are faster than the displayer. Without a bound, the queue would in that case just accumulate those items, which is effectively a memory leak. With the bound, it will make `Queue.put` when the queue is full wait until there is a free slot before letting it proceed.

Answer (score 4):

`asyncio.create_task` *schedules* execution, so it doesn't block event loop.

Rather than appending and popping, would be simpler if task remember their indices in `list`. This example uses `asyncio.Event` to trigger stop replenishing done tasks, and each `coroutines` are wrapped with wrapper to keep indices.

```py
import asyncio
import random


async def wrapper(id_, queue, coroutine):
    await queue.put((id_, f'task {id_:2} completed after {await coroutine}'))


async def some_task():
    delay = random.uniform(0.5, 2)
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    return delay


async def stop_event_delayed(event: asyncio.Event):
    # insert stop value after 10 seconds
    await asyncio.sleep(6)
    print("Sending Stop signal!")
    event.set()


async def wait_until_val(queue: asyncio.Queue, end_val, callback):

    while (val := await queue.get()) is not end_val:
        queue.task_done()
        await callback(*val)

    queue.task_done()
    print("Received sentinel!")


def any_task_alive(task_list) -> bool:
    return any(not task.done() for task in task_list)


async def task_manager(pool_size):
    result_queue = asyncio.Queue()
    stop_event = asyncio.Event()

    # initialize pool with tasks
    pool = [asyncio.create_task(wrapper(idx, result_queue, some_task())) for idx in range(pool_size)]

    async def add_task_callback(idx, msg):
        # change task if event is not set
        if not stop_event.is_set():
            pool[idx] = asyncio.create_task(wrapper(idx, result_queue, some_task()))
        print(msg)
        # do some 'async' works here.

    # wait 10 secs before sending sentinel. Non-blocking, next line will run immediately.
    asyncio.create_task(stop_event_delayed(stop_event))

    # run consumer task to fetch and process tasks.
    consumer = asyncio.create_task(wait_until_val(result_queue, None, add_task_callback))

    # now wait until event, then put sentinel to stop replacing tasks.
    await stop_event.wait()
    await result_queue.put(None)

    # wait until sentinel is processed.
    await consumer


asyncio.run(task_manager(5))
```

```
task  0 completed after 0.8840346369824601
task  4 completed after 0.8930680460954881
task  3 completed after 1.4510289596571013
task  2 completed after 1.6330140843418124
task  1 completed after 1.8027946604246798
task  0 completed after 1.015211866166258
task  3 completed after 0.8812113138160783
task  4 completed after 1.5566122527720068
task  1 completed after 1.1451157417516273
task  0 completed after 1.072688315915855
task  2 completed after 1.751008540755382
task  4 completed after 1.529157768479987
task  3 completed after 1.84274680022116
task  0 completed after 1.4290542578696022
task  2 completed after 1.486182291815456
task  1 completed after 1.9366319822607685
task  4 completed after 1.3291233078722962
task  3 completed after 1.454567007888481
Sending Stop signal!
Received sentinel!
```