# Processing requests in FastAPI sequentially while staying responsive

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi

My server exposes an API for a resource-intensive rendering work. The job it does involves a GPU and as such the server can handle only a single request at a time. Client should submit a job and receive `201` - ACCEPTED - as a response immediately after. The processing can take up to a minute and there can be a few dozens of requests scheduled.

Here's what I came up with, boiled to a minimal reproducible example:

```py
import time
import asyncio
from fastapi import FastAPI, status


app = FastAPI()
fifo_queue = asyncio.Queue()


async def process_requests():
    while True:
        name = await fifo_queue.get()  # Wait for a request from the queue
        print(name)
        time.sleep(10)  # A RESOURCE INTENSIVE JOB THAT BLOCKS THE THREAD
        fifo_queue.task_done()  # Indicate that the request has been processed


@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    asyncio.create_task(process_requests())  # Start the request processing task


@app.get("/render")
async def render(name):
    fifo_queue.put_nowait(name)  # Add the request parameter to the queue
    return status.HTTP_201_CREATED  # Return a 201 status code
```

The problem with this approach is that the server does not stay responsive. After sending the first request it gets busy full time with it and does not respond as I have hoped.

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/render\?name\=001
```

In this example simply replacing `time.sleep(10)` with `await asyncio.sleep(10)` solves the problem, but not in the real use case (though possibly offers a clue as for what I am doing incorrectly).

Any ideas?

Comment: for  each request given to run, assign it some id and return the id to api call  , save result in db or somewhere and then for that id ask the 3rd party to check status. doing current approach with multiple request your system will running full throtle

Comment: @sahasrara62 sure, that's what would normally happen, but I just wanted to keep things simple

Comment: check this out if this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63967662/pool-of-async-tasks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may have figured out already, the main issue in your example is that you run a *synchronous* **blocking** operation within an `async def` endpoint, which blocks the event loop, and hence, the entire server. As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804), if one has to use an `async def` endpoint, they could run such CPU-bound tasks in an external `ProcessPool` and then `await` it (using `asyncio`'s [`loop.run_in_executor()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor)), which would return control back to the event loop, until that task is completed—please have a look at the linked answer above, as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77941425/17865804) for more details. As explained in the linked answers, when using [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) on Windows, it is important to protect the entry point of the program to avoid recursive spawning of subprocesses, etc. Basically, your code must be under `if __name__ == '__main__'` (as shown in the example below).

I would also suggest using a `lifespan` handler, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322910/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804), instead of the deprecated  `startup` and `shutdown` event handlers, to start the `process_requests` function, as well as instantiate the [`asyncio.Queue()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html) and the `ProcessPoolExecutor`, and then add them to the `request.state`, so that they can be shared and re-used by every request/endpoint (especially, in the case of `ProcessPoolExecutor`, to avoid creating a new `ProcessPool` every time, as the computational costs for setting up processes can become expensive, when creating and destroying a lot of processes over and over).

Further, I would suggest creating a unique ID for every request arrived, and return that ID to the client, so that they can use it to check on the status of their request, i.e., whether is completed or still pending processing. You could save that ID to your database storage (or a Key-Value store, such as Redis), as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71537393/17865804); however, for simplicity and demo purposes, the example belows uses a `dict` object for that purpose.

### Working Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from dataclasses import dataclass
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import time
import asyncio
import uuid


@dataclass
class Item:
    id: str
    name: str
    

# Computationally Intensive Task
def cpu_bound_task(item: Item):
    print(f"Processing: {item.name}")
    time.sleep(15)
    return 'ok'


async def process_requests(q: asyncio.Queue, pool: ProcessPoolExecutor):
    while True:
        item = await q.get()  # Get a request from the queue
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        fake_db[item.id] = 'Processing...'
        r = await loop.run_in_executor(pool, cpu_bound_task, item)
        q.task_done()  # tell the queue that the processing on the task is completed
        fake_db[item.id] = 'Done.'


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    q = asyncio.Queue()  # note that asyncio.Queue() is not thread safe
    pool = ProcessPoolExecutor()
    asyncio.create_task(process_requests(q, pool))  # Start the requests processing task
    yield {'q': q, 'pool': pool}
    pool.shutdown()  # free any resources that the pool is using when the currently pending futures are done executing


fake_db = {}
app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


@app.get("/add")
async def add_task(request: Request, name: str):
    item_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    item = Item(item_id, name)
    request.state.q.put_nowait(item)  # Add request to the queue
    fake_db[item_id] = 'Pending...'
    return item_id
    

@app.get("/status")
async def check_status(item_id: str):
    if item_id in fake_db:
        return {'status': fake_db[item_id]}
    else:
        return JSONResponse("Item ID Not Found", status_code=404)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app)
```

##### Note

In case you encountered any memory leak—i.e., memory that is no longer needed, but is not released—when re-using a `ProcessPoolExecutor`, likely due to issues with some third-party library that you might be using, you could instead create a new instance of the `ProcessPoolExecutor` class for every request that needs to be processed and have it terminated (using the `with` statement) right after the processing is completed. Note, however, that creating and destroying many processes over and over could become **computationally expensive**. Example:

```py
async def process_requests(q: asyncio.Queue):
    while True:
        # ...
        with ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
            r = await loop.run_in_executor(pool, cpu_bound_task, item)
        # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for going the extra mile! It improves over my answer, hence accepting it. There's one bit that could be addressed: the `cpu_bound_task` should take `Item` as an argument, not just a string. Why it matters: making this change leads to this error: `TypeError: no default __reduce__ due to non-trivial __cinit__`. Could you address it? The problem seems to be with passing `request` within the `Item`. Removing fixes the problem, but I am curious if there's a way to make it work.

Comment: That was the idea, i.e., to pass the `Item` object as the argument. However, a `ProcessingPool` pickles the objects when it sends them to another process, and having the `request` object part of it would fail serialization - plus, not sure if it  would make much sense to persist objects scuh as `request`. Regardless, in the example, the `request` object is not actually used by the CPU-bound task; if you think it would make it more clear to you, I could have it removed and pass the `Item` as an argument, and explain that any information the `request` holds could be passed as separate arguments.

Comment: I think simply removing request from the `Item` makes most sense in this example, IMO no need to explain how to pass more data.

BTW, what would be the best way to mark that item is being processed, something like `fake_db[item_id] = 'Processing...'`. I tried that assignment in the `cpu_bound_task`, but the dict wasn't modified. I can't use an actual db in this case.

Comment: Updated. If you wouldn't like using some database storage or Key-Value cache, which would allow you to share variables/objects among the various processes (as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71537393/17865804), each process, and uvicorn worker as well, has its own variables and memory; that is why you can't update the `dict` object within the separate process), you could simply update the value of the relevant key in `fake_db`, jsut before calling `run_in_executor` (shown in the example above).

Comment: Thanks! One word of explanation behind NOT reusing the `Pool` object: when we intentionally want to kill the process. My rendering uses library on occasions does not fully release resources, in particular memory on GPU. Since the process really needs all the memory, it sometimes leads to `CUDA: out of memory error`. Mentioning just in case someone ventures into similar waters.

Answer (score 1):

The basic thing that I missed is that in asyncio one can't do anything blocking in a function marked async or it will freeze the event loop.

**Solution**

Run the process with the asyncio event loop `run_in_executor`. The method allows to run the code in a process pool and returns an awaitable. Since it runs in a separate process, the main loop stays responsive.

```
import time
import asyncio
from fastapi import FastAPI, status
from functools import partial
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


app = FastAPI()
fifo_queue = asyncio.Queue()


def compute_intensive_func(name):
    print(name)
    time.sleep(10)
    return 43

async def process_requests():
    while True:
        name = await fifo_queue.get()  # Wait for a request from the queue
        r = await asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(pool, partial(compute_intensive_func, name))
        fifo_queue.task_done()  # Indicate that the request has been processed


@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    asyncio.create_task(process_requests())  # Start the request processing task


@app.get("/render")
async def render(name):
    fifo_queue.put_nowait(name)  # Add the request parameter to the queue
    return status.HTTP_201_CREATED  # Return a 201 status code
```

Answer (score 0):

The function that is running the GPU-related code needs to run as an async function.

As the code is written in your example, the same asyncio loop is being used for both request handling and for processing; that loop switches between code at await points. When you do time.sleep(10), the thread that is running the asyncio loop is now sleeping for 10 seconds with no await point. When you do asyncio.sleep(10), the sleep instruction is handed off to a background thread and the asyncio loop thread is available to handle incoming requests, etc, and the server appears responsive and the await point is reached after that background task has waited for 10 seconds.

EDIT: The accepted answer here is alot more detailed

[What does asyncio.create_task() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62528272/what-does-asyncio-create-task-do)

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that the `create_task` would actually start the thread. How would you approach this particular case? Simply create an extra function `fun()` to be called within `process_request` like this `asyncio.run(fun())`? Change anything else?

Comment: yes, I think you can just make whatever GPU function you have now an async function and run it in awaitable fashion.

Comment: When I try doing this, I get `asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop` If I get the current event loop, but that gets me where I have started. If I make the resource-heavy `fun()` async and go with `await fun()` inside `process_requests()` I again get unresponsive server.