# FastAPI Background task in loop is not working

Tags: background, task, fastapi

I'm running FastAPI background task like below.

And process_video_with_model() extract data from image with vision model and it takes about 10~20 minutes.

It worked  when running this function with start_video_task().
But when I run start_video_list_task()(the video list has more than 100 videos information and gpu is being used), but the video is not being processed.

```
def bgtask(info):
    process_video_with_model(info)
    return {"message": "Job Created"}

@router.post("")
async def start_video_task(info: Info, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    msg = background_tasks.add_task(bgtask, info)
    print(f'{video_info} msg['message']')

def start_video_list_task(video_info_list):
    for video_info in video_info_list:
        msg = background_tasks.add_task(bgtask, info)
        print(f'{video_info} msg['message']')
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: In addition to the link above, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77941425/17865804), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70873984/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77862153/17865804), as well as all the referenced answers included in them