# Python: Execute long-running task in a background process forking off FastAPI app

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess, python-asyncio, fastapi

## TL;DR

In my `gunicorn/uvicorn`-run FastAPI app, I need to execute some long-running tasks in a completely non-blocking way, so the main `asyncio` event loop is not affected. The only approach I can think of is spinning off separate processes to fire the tasks and then somehow collect the results and signal the main loop. So basically, my workflow should look something like:

```
1. Fire task in separate process (do ffmpeg video encoding and save files/data).
2. Forget about the running process and do other stuff in a normal way.
3. Get "I'm done" signal from the process(es) and check for errors.
4. Handle results.
```

## The long-running stuff

My long-running task calls `ffmpeg` video encoder on some files, actually using `asyncio.subprocess` to fork an external `ffmpeg` process. Then it does some file operations on the resulting files, and stores some data in the app's database. The code looks as follows (simplified version):

```py
import ffmpeg  # ffmpeg-python (https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/)
import asyncio
from pydantic import BaseModel

class ProcessResultModel(BaseModel):
    returncode: int = None
    stdout: str = ''
    stderr: str = ''

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True

@ffmpeg.nodes.output_operator()
async def run_async_async(stream_spec, cmd='ffmpeg', pipe_stdin=False, pipe_stdout=False,
                          pipe_stderr=False, quiet=False, overwrite_output=False,
                          run: bool = True) -> Union[asyncio.subprocess.Process, ProcessResultModel]:
    # compile ffmpeg args
    args = ffmpeg._run.compile(stream_spec, cmd, overwrite_output=overwrite_output)
    # pipe streams as required
    stdin_stream = asyncio.subprocess.PIPE if pipe_stdin else None
    stdout_stream = asyncio.subprocess.PIPE if pipe_stdout or quiet else None
    stderr_stream = asyncio.subprocess.PIPE if pipe_stderr or quiet else None
    # create subprocess (ffmpeg)
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*args, stdin=stdin_stream,
                                                    stdout=stdout_stream, stderr=stderr_stream)
    # if not told to run, simply return the process object
    if not run: return process
    # run process and collect results
    stdout, stderr = await process.communicate()
    # return results in a nice object
    return ProcessResultModel(returncode=process.returncode,
                              stdout=stdout.decode('utf-8') if stdout else '',
                              stderr=stderr.decode('utf-8') if stderr else '')
```

## The problem

If I simply call this in my FastAPI CRUD function as is:

```py
async def fire_task(stream):
    res = await stream.run_async_async(run=True)
```

it will call `process.communicate()` and effectually block my main event loop until the entire task is done. If I call it with `run=False`, it will just return the initialized process which I will need to start somewhere myself.

Is there a way to fire-and-forget the process without blocking the event loop and then at some point, get the process to signalize that it's done and collect the results - in a safe and robust manner?

Comment: A common solution to this sort of problem is some sort of job queue, e.g. as implemented by [Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html).

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71738644/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: Please have a look at related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77941425/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77862153/17865804)

Comment: Yes, many thanks! The links above gave me a winning clue. See updated post.

Answer (score 0):

So after perusing the replies to similar questions mentioned here (thanks @Chris), I finally managed to put together a working solution. See below.

### [1] FastAPI App lifespan

Instantiate global singleton thread pool in the app's lifespan:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

POOL_MAX_THREADS = 20

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    # create thread pool for long-runners
    pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=POOL_MAX_THREADS)
    
    # do other initialization / regular tasks
    await on_startup_single(app)
    await regular_tasks_5min()

    # yield globals (will be accessible in requests)
    yield {'pool': pool}

    # do shutdown activities
    await on_shutdown_single(app)
    pool.shutdown()
```

### [2] FastAPI Endpoint(s)

Pass global pool to underlying CRUD functions from the endpoints via `Request`:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter, Request, Body
import crud  # app's CRUD functions

router = APIRouter()

@router.post('/do-stuff')
async def do_stuff(request: Request, data: dict = Body(...)):
    # pass global thread pool in request state
    await crud.do_stuff(data, request.state.pool)
```

### [3] CRUD function

Prepare params and fire long-running task in the thread pool:

```py
from concurrent.futures import Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor
import asyncio

POOL_MAX_THREADS = 20

# the long-running worker we need to run in a non-blocking fashion
async def very_long_task(data):
    await one()
    await two()
    return await three()

# the task-spawning function
async def do_stuff(data: dict, pool: Executor = None)
    # we may also choose to execute in a default pool
    if pool is None: pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=POOL_MAX_THREADS)
    # get main event loop
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    # fire task and return immediately, leaving the task to run in thread pool
    loop.run_in_executor(pool, lambda: asyncio.run(very_long_task(data)))
```

That's it basically!

### PS.

I couldn't manage to get the code working with the other suggested solutions, including `ProcessPoolExecutor` instead of `ThreadPoolExecutor`, or using `asyncio.Queue` to take tasks off the queue as they appear.

Comment: The question is closed, as solutions on this issue could be found in similar questions asked/answered in the recent past (as shown from your answer above as well). Though, please note that your `very_long_task()` function seems to be very dfferent from what you initially implied it was. The solution you used and which was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71738644/17865804) makes sense when the background task function is defined with `async def`, as you had to `await` for some coroutines inside, but at the same time you had to execute some *synchronous* blocking function

Comment: In your question you said that you had some long-running task that you would like to run in a separate process. The *long-running task* suggests that you have some *synchronous/blocking* CPU-bound operation; however, your `very_long_task()` only shows `await`ing for coroutines inside. If that's really the case, you should then run that function directly in the event loop using `asyncio.create_task()`, as demonstrated in Option 3 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70873984/17865804).

Comment: Otherwise, if there are blocking CPU-bound operations inside then keep using the method above - if you don't have to share any objects with that function (such as the `websocket` object in the linked answer), you should rather use a ProcessPool instead of ThreadPool (if it is about a CPU-bound task). Note that just because you may define a custom function with `async def` and then `await` it, it doesn't mean that your code will work asynchronously, if that custom function contains calls to blocking operations. Please read all the links provided above to better understand these concepts.

Comment: Thanks, Chris! The code snippet I show for `very_long_task()` may be misleading, since it gives an appearance of a simple awaitable that can be run in the main loop. In reality, it is not, and the functions it awaits internally are all CPU-blocking - ffmpeg transcoding processes, in fact. So yes, I am currently sticking with the suggested pool-based solution, although I am beginning to think a simple `subprocess.Popen()` with `ffmpeg` executable would be much simpler and more apposite.